# Interleave rows of MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing data and a class, something like

```
----------------
| DATA | Class |
----------------
|  1   |   A   |
|  2   |   A   |
|  5   |   B   |
|  10  |   A   |
|  2   |   A   |
|  45  |   B   |
|  90  |   B   |
----------------
```

I would like to interleave the two classes to obtain something like this:

```
----------------
| DATA | Class |
----------------
|  1   |   A   |
|  5   |   B   |
|  2   |   A   |
|  45  |   B   |
|  2   |   A   |
|  90  |   B   |
|  10  |   A   |
----------------
```

I thought about generating on the fly an additional column that will add a sequential incrementing index to each separate class and sort on that one, but need a good direction/pointer to do that.

Something like:

```
-----------------------
| DATA | Class | indx |
-----------------------
|  1   |   A   |  1   |
|  5   |   B   |  1   |
|  2   |   A   |  2   |
|  45  |   B   |  2   |
|  2   |   A   |  3   |
|  90  |   B   |  3   |
|  10  |   A   |  4   |
-----------------------
```

Is it even possible using only MySQL?

Comment: SQL tables represent unordered sets, so they have no inherent order.  Hence, there is no concept of interleaving, unless you have a column that specifying the ordering.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It looks like he effectively wants to sort the A rows and the B rows by the DATA column, and then alternate between the first row in the (sorted) A set, first row in the B set, second row in the A set, etc.  This should be possible using variables (I have seen such a query before) but it's a bit convoluted.

Comment: @cdhowie you nailed it.

Comment: @2dvisio This probably is possible in MySQL but would be cleaner to implement in the application.  At the very least I would suggest using a stored procedure to hide the ugliness if you do implement it using SQL.

Comment: @cdhowie I can implement this in the application with few lines of code. But got so frustrated I cannot do it that I had to post the question to see how easy it is to do it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enumerate each class independently, and then order by the enumeration:

```
select data, class, idx
from (select a.*,
             (@seqnum := if(@class = class, @seqnum + 1,
                            if(@class := class, 1, 1)
                           )
             ) as idx
      from atable a cross join
           (select @class := NULL, @seqnum := 0) vars
      order by class, data
     ) a
order by idx, class;
```

EDIT:

This query enumerates each class independently, so the row with the smallest data gets a value of 1 and so on.  It is using MySQL variables for this purpose.  In other databases, you would use `row_number()`.  Once you have the enumeration, the final step is just to sort by that field.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'd appreciate if you can give brief explanation on how this SQL work or a reference on the corresponding manual. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Stepashka . . . I tried, but if you don't understand variables in MySQL, then you should practice with them to get a feel for them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SQL I can suggest:

```
SET @rank:=0;
update aabb set `index` = @rank:=@rank+2 where `class` = 'A';
SET @rank:=1;
update aabb set `index` = @rank:=@rank+2 where `class` = 'B';
select * from aabb order by `index`;
```

Comment: I can have more than 2 classes, and I don't know a priori their number :(

Comment: In case there are more than 2 classes then you need them to be A,B,C,D,A,B,C,D ? Are classes always 1 letter?

Comment: good question! No, they are a VarChar of fixed length. Any clue?